# Explicit separability idempotent for the center of a separable algebra

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, separable-algebras

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra for some commutative ring $k$. Recall that $A$ is said to be separable over $k$ if the multiplication map $A\otimes_k A^{\operatorname{op}}\to A$ has a section as a map of $A\otimes_k A^{\operatorname{op}}$-modules.

It is shown in [AG] (theorem 2.3) that in that case the center of $A$, $Z(A)$ is also separable over $k$. The proof is somewhat abstract, and in particular it does not seem easy to extract from it the following type of construction: "start with a separability idempotent for $A$, do something with it, and get a separability idempotent for $Z(A)$" (recall that a separability idempotent for $A$ is the image of $1\in A$ under an $A\otimes_k A^{\operatorname{op}}$-linear section of the multiplication; it is in particular an idempotent of the ring $A\otimes_k A^{\operatorname{op}}$)

They also refer to another paper of Eilenberg-Rosenberg-Zelinsky, but it doesn't seem to contain something explicit either. So my question is:

> Given a separability idempotent for $A$, is there an explicit formula to cook up a separability idempotent for $Z(A)$ ?

Note that in general, $A$ can have several separability idempotents, but $Z(A)$ can only have one as it is commutative, but I'm fine with any type of formula, even if it looks like it depends on a choice of separability idempotent.

Here is one thing one might naively try, that does not work: the separability idempotent $s\in A\otimes_k A^{\operatorname{op}}$ yields a retraction $r: A\to Z(A)$ given by $x\mapsto s\cdot x$ (where $s\cdot x := \sum_i s_ixt_i$ if $s= \sum_i s_i\otimes t_i$). One could then try to apply $r\otimes r: A\otimes A\to Z(A)\otimes Z(A)$ to $s$ itself - however, this does not work.

Can something along those lines work ?

[AG]: Auslander-Goldman, *The Brauer group of a commutative ring*